# invalid operands to binary expression nsstring and id

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am getting the errer invalid operends to binary expression nsstring and id even i  use typecasting  this is the code in which i have problem . kindly correct this code.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j<newarray.count ; j++){
        if(j<newarray.count){
 message = (NSString *) message + [newarray objectAtIndex:j]+ "," ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `+` operator with objects, for your specific case you may replace the whole cycle with:

```
NSString* message = [newarray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

And FIY Objective-C does not support operator overloading at all.

Comment: Wow how'd I overlook that! Much more efficient of a solution than mine +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this was your intention, but if you were trying to append new information to the string separated by commas you could go with something like this:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j<newarray.count ; j++){
    [message stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[newarray objectAtIndex:j]]];
}
```

Additionally, your condition `if(j<newarray.count)` would always evaluate true in this loop, and is therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast "[newarray objectAtIndex:j]", whose default return type is "id"

[Check this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex%3a)

Also IIRC NSString doesn't have + operand overloaded. So maybe you should try [NSString stringWithFormat:].

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming `NSString` acts like `std::string` in C++.  Try this:

```
NSMutableString *message = ...;
for (unsigned j = 0; j < newarray.count; j++)
{
    if (j > 0)
        [message appendString:@", "];
    [message appendString:[newarray objectAtIndex:j]];
}
```